# Generating DOC (and DOCX) templates using Python or Java with absolute positioned boxes

Tags: java, python, ms-word, docx, doc

For a web-to-print we need to generate a .doc (Microsoft Word 2003+) compatible templates/documents where we need to position some data inside the document (basically we need to auto-generated letter heads for address, phone, contact information etc.).

Which Python or Java based solutions can be used here that providing support for absolute positioning of text boxes in .doc (perhaps even through .DOCX).

We tried: XFC (FO-based which does not support absolute positioning) and tried Aspose Words for Java (also no support for absolute positioning).

Money does not play a major role. The solution has to work and it must not be open-source.

Any more options?

Comment: Why not open source? Is it an issue of support?

Comment: I said clearly that I am looking for a *working solution* - and I don't care if it is open-source or not. Software has to work.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do with word, you can do with the word com object.

1. Install PythonWin.
2. Use the object browser under "Tools->COM browser" to find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) since it works from a template.  You would do something like absolute-position your text box in the template and use Docmosis to put populate the text box.   You could probably lay out the entire page as a table grid as another approach - it will likely on the specifics of the layout of the other components as well.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice.org's Universal Network Objects (UNO),  allow you to generate *.doc,*.PDF,  as well as OpenOffice documents. It supports several programming languages like: Java, C++, Visual Basic, etcc..

Some good things is that: its free, open source and plataform-independent

You can build documents, spreadsheets, presentations, etc. 
The library allow you to create graph, charts and start from scratch or using a template and fill the gaps..

In order to use it you will need to include some libraries that comes with the OpenOffice suite.

Useful links:

- [Open Office home](http://www.openoffice.org)
- [Open Office UNO Developer's Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide)